# Python: how to type hint a dataclass?

Tags: python, python-typing, python-dataclasses

The code below works, but I'm getting the following warning by PyCharm:

> Cannot find reference `__annotations__` in '(...) -> Any'.

I guess it's because I'm using `Callable`. I didn't find something like `Dataclass`. Which type should I use instead?

```
from __future__ import annotations
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Callable

@dataclass
class Fruit:
  color: str
  taste: str

def get_cls() -> Callable:
  return Fruit

attrs = get_cls().__annotations__  # <- IDE warning
print(attrs)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this particular example you can just hint it directly:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Fruit:
    x: str

def get_cls() -> type[Fruit]:
    return Fruit

attrs = get_cls().__annotations__
print(attrs)
```

```bash
$ python d.py
{'x': <class 'str'>}
$ mypy d.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

However I don't know if this is what you're asking.  Are you after a generic type for any dataclass?  (I would be tempted just to hint the union of all possible return types of `get_cls()`: the whole point about using a dataclass rather than e.g. a dict is surely to distinguish between types of data.  And you do want your typechecker to warn you if you try to access attributes not defined on one of your dataclasses.)

### References

See [the docs on `typing.Type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type) which is now available as `type` (just like we can now use `list` and `dict` rather than `typing.List` and `typing.Dict`).

Answer (score 3):

The ***simplest option*** is to remove the return type annotation in its entirety.

> Note: PyCharm is usually smart enough to infer the return type automatically.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from dataclasses import dataclass
# remove this line
# from typing import Callable

@dataclass
class Fruit:
  color: str
  taste: str

# def get_cls() -> Callable:  <== No, the return annotation is wrong (Fruit is *more* than a callable)
def get_cls():
  return Fruit


attrs = get_cls().__annotations__  # <- No IDE warning, Yay!
print(attrs)
```

In PyCharm, the return type is correctly inferred:

[image]

---

To ***generically type hint a dataclass*** - since *dataclasses* are essentially Python classes under the hood, with auto-generated methods and some "extra" class attributes added in to the mix, you could just type hint it with [`typing.Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) as shown below:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from dataclasses import dataclass, Field
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Any, Callable, Iterable, Protocol


if TYPE_CHECKING:
    # this won't print
    print('Oh YEAH !!')

    class DataClass(Protocol):
        __dict__: dict[str, Any]
        __doc__: str | None
        # if using `@dataclass(slots=True)`
        __slots__: str | Iterable[str]
        __annotations__: dict[str, str | type]
        __dataclass_fields__: dict[str, Field]
        # the actual class definition is marked as private, and here I define
        # it as a forward reference, as I don't want to encourage
        # importing private or "unexported" members.
        __dataclass_params__: '_DataclassParams'
        __post_init__: Callable | None


@dataclass
class Fruit:
    color: str
    taste: str


# noinspection PyTypeChecker
def get_cls() -> type[DataClass]:
    return Fruit


attrs = get_cls().__annotations__  # <- No IDE warning, Yay!
```

##### Costs to `class` def

To address the comments, there does appear to be a non-negligible runtime cost associated to class definitions - hence why I wrap the def with an `if` block above.

The following code compares the performance with both approaches, to confirm this suspicion:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from dataclasses import dataclass, Field
from timeit import timeit
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Any, Callable, Iterable, Protocol


n = 100_000

print('class def:  ', timeit("""
class DataClass(Protocol):
    __dict__: dict[str, Any]
    __doc__: str | None
    __slots__: str | Iterable[str]
    __annotations__: dict[str, str | type]
    __dataclass_fields__: dict[str, Field]
    __dataclass_params__: '_DataclassParams'
    __post_init__: Callable | None
""", globals=globals(), number=n))

print('if <bool>:  ', timeit("""
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    class DataClass(Protocol):
        __dict__: dict[str, Any]
        __doc__: str | None
        __slots__: str | Iterable[str]
        __annotations__: dict[str, str | type]
        __dataclass_fields__: dict[str, Field]
        __dataclass_params__: '_DataclassParams'
        __post_init__: Callable | None
""", globals=globals(), number=n))
```

Results, on Mac M1 running Python 3.10:

```
class def:   0.7453760829521343
if <bool>:   0.0009954579873010516
```

Hence, it appears to be much faster overall to wrap a `class` definition (when used purely for type hinting purposes) with an `if` block as above.

Comment: I don't think removing an annotation entirely is **ever** a good solution. The protocol is an interesting approach though. I wrote a critique in my own answer here. I just wanted to point out that I don't think this constitutes a _generic_ type hint as your `DataClass` type is _not_ generic. It is more of a structural subtyping approach. Albeit a contentious one. :) (And as a small side note, I don't think there is any need for the `TYPE_CHECKING` condition here, as there are no runtime problems or costs with the class definition.)

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg A good point in the first regard - however, I would argue that there is a *non-negligible* runtime cost associated with a class definition. I updated my answer above to add a sample code to explore this a little better.

Answer (score 3):

While the provided solutions do work, I just want to add a bit of context.

IMHO your annotation is **not wrong**. It is just not strict enough and not all that useful.

`Fruit` is a class. And technically speaking a class **is** a callable because `type` (the class of all classes) implements the `__call__` method. In fact, that method is executed *every time* you create an instance of a class; even before the class' `__init__` method. (For details refer to the *"Callable types"* subsection in [this section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) of the data model docs.)

One problem with your annotation however, is that [`Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) is a generic type. Thus, you should specify its type arguments. In this case you would have a few options, depending on how narrow you want your annotation to be. The simplest one that would still be correct here is the "catch-all" callable:

```py
def get_cls() -> Callable[..., Any]:
    return Fruit
```

But since you know that **calling** the class `Fruit` returns an **instance** of that class, you might as well write this:

```py
def get_cls() -> Callable[..., Fruit]:
    return Fruit
```

Finally, if you know which arguments will be allowed for instantiating a `Fruit` (namely the `color` and `taste` attributes you defined on the dataclass), you could narrow it down even further:

```py
def get_cls() -> Callable[[str, str], Fruit]:
    return Fruit
```

Technically, all of those are correct. (Try it with `mypy --strict`.)

However, even that last annotation is not particularly useful since `Fruit` is not just *any* `Callable` returning a `Fruit` instance, it **is the class `Fruit` itself**. Therefore the most sensible annotation is (as [@2e0byo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74153466/19770795) pointed out) this one:

```py
def get_cls() -> type[Fruit]:
    return Fruit
```

That is what I would do as well.

---

I disagree with [@rv.kvetch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74154322/19770795) that removing the annotation is a solution (in **any** situation).

His `DataClass` protocol is an interesting proposal. However I would advise against it in this case for a few reasons:

1. It might give you all the magic attributes that make up *any* dataclass, but annotating with it makes you lose all information about the *actualy* specific class you return from `get_cls`, namely `Fruit`. In practical terms this means **no auto-suggestions** by the IDE of `Fruit`-specific attributes/methods.
2. You still have to place a type checker exception/ignore in `get_cls` because in the eyes of any static type checker `type[Fruit]` is **not** a subtype of `type[DataClass]`. The built-in dataclass protocol is a hack that is carried by specially tailored plugins for `mypy`, `PyCharm` etc. and those do not cover this kind of structural subtyping.
3. Even the forward reference to `_DataclassParams` is still a problem because it will never be resolved, *unless* you (surprise, surprise) import that protected member from the depths of the `dataclasses` package. Thus, this is not a stable annotation.

So from a type safety standpoint, there are two big errors in that code -- the subtyping and the unresolved reference -- and two minor errors; those being the non-parameterized generic annotations for `__dataclass_fields__` (`Field` is generic) and `__post_init__` (`Callable` is generic).

Still, I like protocols. Python is a protocol-oriented language. The approach is interesting.

Comment: I shudder at the protocol suggestion (and things like typing.Interface).  Leave my beautiful clean scripting language alone! But I do agree it's interesting.  Nice walk-through with `Callable`.